# How to take my fetched Json and render it in table? (Best practice)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have a single page application where I want to display json data fetched from an url API and display said data within my rendered Table. Whats the best way to do so from the code I have below.

```
function App() {
  const marURL = "https://blah/getMarkets.php";

  function PullJson() {
    fetch(marURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        // **MarketData = responseData?**
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    PullJson();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">Admin Market Data Collection</header>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Market ID</th>
            <th>Market Alpha</th>
            <th>Completion Time</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
          </tr>
          {MarketData.map((market) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{market.marketName}</td>
                <td>{market.marketId}</td>
                <td>{market.marketAlpha}</td>
                <td>{market.completionTime}</td>
                <td>{market.startTime}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The issue lies within the way to get the fetched object to a var called marketData which is being mapped. I want to render json data in the render call. Need some sort of global variable called MarketData

How do I go about that?

Comment: You need to add `const [marketData, setMarketData] = useState([]);` at the top of your function. In your fetch's 2nd then callback, you do `setMarketData(responseData);`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `marketData` a state atom with `useState` and `set` the fetched data into it.

I've opted for `[]`, an empty array, as the default for `marketData` here, but you might want to consider `null` (with a guard such as `if(marketData === null) return <>Loading...</>`) to avoid flashing an empty table at your user.

(This is a simplified example that's missing e.g. error handling; you might want to look at [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) for a better data-fetching hook.)

```
const marURL = "https://blah/getMarkets.php";

function App() {
  const [marketData, setMarketData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(marURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setMarketData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">Admin Market Data Collection</header>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Market</th>
            <th>Market ID</th>
            <th>Market Alpha</th>
            <th>Completion Time</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
          </tr>
          {marketData.map((market) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{market.marketName}</td>
                <td>{market.marketId}</td>
                <td>{market.marketAlpha}</td>
                <td>{market.completionTime}</td>
                <td>{market.startTime}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Rehashing basic parts of the doc on SO, part #4309574304

Comment: @ChrisG Can you point out where "the doc" shows how to use `fetch` and `useEffect` in conjunction with `useState`?

Comment: OP has the first two in place and working. What's missing was using state to store and render data, which is an essential concept and explained in detail in the documentation.

Comment: FYI @ChrisG the introductory documentation isn't particularly helpful re state and lifecycle for function components because all the examples use class components.

Comment: @Andy I was referring to this part: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use State in react instead of Global Variable.

```
const [MarketData,setMarketData] = useState([])

fetch(marURL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData);
        setMarketData(responseData)
      });
```

Comment: You would use a blank array `[]` as initial value here or you'll get an error during rendering.